# Ubuntu 15.10 apparently stuck on kernel 3.16.0-38 generic

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, 15.10

Yesterday, I have run my Ubuntu partition for the first time in atleast 5 months. I have ran

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Which took about 2 hours to run. This morning, I ran the command again, as I normally do. It didn't give me any updates, but once I changed from the MA servers to the US servers, it gave me a few updates. I then ran

```
uname -r
```

which gave me the following result:

```
3.16.0-38-generic
```

indicating that the kernel did not upgrade to 4.2 or 4.1.
My question is: How do I upgrade the kernel to the following releases?
Thanks!

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` - I would encourage you to make a backup of all of your important data before you engage in a lot of system modification, though!

Comment: Thanks. I do not have any important data on this partition, it is mostly for tinkering.

**EDIT** - It seems to have worked.

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the command `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

This will add the meta-package `linux-generic` to your list of installed applications, and attempt to bring your kernel to the version specified in the repositories for Ubuntu 15.10